# Why is my dockerized node application running into a heap limit Allocation error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm going through a tutorial from the docker website to set up a node developing environment
The program seemingly runs as intended, in fact running normally through node the program has no issues

```
const ronin         = require( 'ronin-server' )
const database  = require( 'ronin-database' )
const mocks         = require( 'ronin-mocks' )

async function main() {

    try {
    await database.connect( process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING )
    //await database.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notes');
    const server = ronin.server({
            port: process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8000
        })

        server.use( '/', mocks.server( server.Router()) )
    server.use('/foo', (req, res) => {
        return res.json('foo: bar');
    });
    const result = await server.start()
        console.info( result )
    
    } catch( error ) {
        console.error( error )
    }
}

main()
```

However when I run through it a docker container it appears to just ramp in memory usage until I get a heap out of memory error

```
node-docker-notes-1  | > docker@1.0.0 start
node-docker-notes-1  | > nodemon server.js
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.313+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.315+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.318+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.318+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.318+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.318+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.319+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.320+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.320+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.321+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.322+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.322+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.323+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.324+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.324+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.324+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.324+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
node-docker-notes-1  | [nodemon] 3.0.1
node-docker-notes-1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
node-docker-notes-1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
node-docker-notes-1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
node-docker-notes-1  | [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.703+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.18.0.3:38568 #1 (1 connection now open)
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:24.708+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 172.18.0.3:38568 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.7.4" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "5.15.49-linuxkit-pr" }, platform: "'Node.js v20.4.0, LE (unified)" }
node-docker-notes-1  | Listening on port 8000
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:25:25.000+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | <--- Last few GCs --->
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | [23:0x7f470259a4b0]   345298 ms: Scavenge 5829.2 (6030.3) -> 5819.6 (6031.3) MB, 10.72 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.216, current mu = 0.013) task; 
node-docker-notes-1  | [23:0x7f470259a4b0]   345332 ms: Scavenge 5832.0 (6031.3) -> 5823.9 (6033.6) MB, 16.47 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.216, current mu = 0.013) task; 
node-docker-notes-1  | [23:0x7f470259a4b0]   347941 ms: Mark-Compact 5834.4 (6033.6) -> 5772.5 (6037.1) MB, 2598.46 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.281, current mu = 0.339) task; scavenge might not succeed
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | <--- JS stacktrace --->
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | npm
node-docker-notes-1  |  
node-docker-notes-1  | ERR!
node-docker-notes-1  |  
node-docker-notes-1  | path
node-docker-notes-1  |  /
node-docker-notes-1  | npm
node-docker-notes-1  |  
node-docker-notes-1  | ERR!
node-docker-notes-1  |  command failed
node-docker-notes-1  | npm
node-docker-notes-1  |  
node-docker-notes-1  | ERR!
node-docker-notes-1  |  
node-docker-notes-1  | signal
node-docker-notes-1  |  SIGABRT
node-docker-notes-1  | npm
node-docker-notes-1  |  
node-docker-notes-1  | ERR! 
node-docker-notes-1  | command
node-docker-notes-1  |  sh -c nodemon server.js
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | 
node-docker-notes-1  | npm
node-docker-notes-1  |  ERR!
node-docker-notes-1  |  A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-21T16_25_24_227Z-debug-0.log
node-docker-mongo-1  | 2023-07-21T16:31:16.333+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.18.0.3:38568 (0 connections now open)
node-docker-notes-1 exited with code 1
```

I've upped the allocated memory and messed about about with the NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size but all that seems to do is delay the issue, is there anything obvious I missing from this that is causing a memory leak?

PS
Docker config files to help as well

```
FROM node:20-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=6000

WORKDIR /

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

```
services:
 notes:
  image: node-docker
  build:
   context: .
  ports:
   - 8000:8000
   - 9229:9229
  environment:
   - SERVER_PORT=8000
   - CONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb://mongo:27017/notes
  volumes:
   - ./:/app
   - /app/node_modules
  command: npm start

 mongo:
  image: mongo:4.2.8
  ports:
   - 27017:27017
  volumes:
   - mongodb:/data/db
   - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
volumes:
 mongodb:
 mongodb_config:
```

Additional info I built my own server code from scratch and still ran into the same issue (albeit my version hasn't got the same logging capabilities yet) the issue persists but takes longer to hit the memory limit